# launchbadge/sqlx: id column type is incorrectly inferred as Option<i64>

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-sqlx

In my to-do application back-end using Actix Web and SQLx crates, along with SQLite database, after the `UPDATE` query I noticed `id` field on the `Record` type is `Option<i64>` instead of `i64`. It's supposed to be `i64` since it is declared as `PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` . The database migration:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todos
(
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    description TEXT                NOT NULL,
    done        BOOLEAN             NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[[bin]]
name = "todos"
path = "src/main.rs"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.3.1"
anyhow = "1.0.71"
dotenvy_macro = "0.15.7"
serde = { version = "1.0.169", features = ["derive"] }
sqlx = { version = "0.7", features = [ "sqlite", "runtime-tokio" ] }
```

Endpoint handler:

```rs
use actix_web::{
    put,
    web::{self, Json},
    HttpResponse, Responder,
};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use crate::AppData;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct ErrorResponse {
    error: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct PutTodoRequest {
    pub id: i64,
    pub description: String,
    pub done: bool,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct TodoResponse {
    pub id: i64,
    pub description: String,
    pub done: bool,
}

#[put("/todo/")]
async fn put_todo(body: Json<PutTodoRequest>, app_data: web::Data<AppData>) -> impl Responder {
    let body = body.into_inner();
    let result = sqlx::query!(
        "UPDATE todos SET description = $1, done = $2 WHERE id = $3 RETURNING *;",
        body.description,
        body.done,
        body.id
    )
    .fetch_one(&app_data.db_pool)
    .await;

    if let Err(e) = result {
        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json(ErrorResponse {
            error: e.to_string(),
        });
    }

    if let Ok(data) = result {
        if let Some(id) = data.id {
            return HttpResponse::Ok().json(TodoResponse {
                id,
                description: data.description,
                done: data.done,
            });
        }

        return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json(ErrorResponse {
            error: "id was null, somehow...".to_owned(),
        });
    }

    HttpResponse::InternalServerError().json(ErrorResponse {
        error: "I did not expect this.".to_owned(),
    })
}
```

For some reason `data.id` is of type `Option<i64>` and I have to use `if let` to check if it's `Option::None`. If that's the case I return:

```rs
ErrorResponse { error: "id was null, somehow...".to_owned() }
```

I thought my migration had failed but even after re-running it with `sqlx migrate run` this issue is still present. I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/1852) which might be related. The [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pureliani/todos-svelte-rs/tree/main/server).

Comment: IIRC this is related to the use of `RETURNING`.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I tried `sqlx` I had to cast variables as well as the returned values. Like `f1 AS INTEGER` or `COALESCE(f1, 0)`, so that the type inference would work as expected. Speaking about the reasons, may be `UPDATE WHERE id = -1` could return a row of NULLs without updating anything (check it) thus triggering sqlx marking the return type as `Option<i64>`.